# Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Byte[]

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, dataadapter, sqlparameter

I'm getting error converting parameters from DateTime to Byte[]. 
The idea is to show data between 2 specified dates that are entered via controls and displayed on GridView, and using a stored procedure to access data. I don't understand the error, but I'm guessing that all the data is put in an Array and passed on to stored procedure:

```
string sDateBegin = Request.Form["fromDate"];
DateTime dtDateBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(sDateBegin);
SqlParameter prmDateBegin = new SqlParameter("datebegin", SqlDbType.Timestamp);
prmDateBegin.Value = dtDateBegin;
cmdProc.Parameters.Add(prmDateBegin);

//same code for DateEnd

// data table
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

AGridView.DataSourceID = null;

// data adapter
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdProc);
AGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

//fill datatable
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Comment: Hello malvina, welcome to StackOverflow. 
We're having some problems seeing exactly what is going on here, because we're missing some information (such as the programming language you are using, and what database engine and/or frameworks you are using).
Please help us help you, by filling in those blanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using .Net framework, C# and MS SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Does the error occur on `DateTime dtDateBegin = Convert.ToDateTime(sDateBegin);` ?

if so, this could maybe be resolved by using `DateTime.Parse(string input)` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx )

The reason i can't be sure yet, is that it is hard to tell what the stored procedure and gridview controls you mentioned are doing ;)

Comment: Thanx Timothy, that actually worked! thanks a million :)

Comment: You're welcome.
I have added an answer that should clarify what was going on :)

Answer (score 3):

You've defined the SqlParameter as a Timestamp data type (which is a byte array) rather than a DateTime.   Given you're representing a date range it sounds like you should change the parameter data type to DateTime.

Comment: +1. And another one not reading the documentation what Timestamp means. I love that. This question is SO suitable in inteviwes for senior people - just a side querstion, get the (wrong answer), take the resume and put it where it belongs - garbage bin. Timestamp data type has nothing to do with timestamps ;)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I have had tried this already and it didn't make any difference, the error was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx) tries to do an implicit conversion from any object to a DateTime.
The object coming from the control is a string, but not one that could be cast to a DateTime object.
It is in fact a date and time represented by a string.

The correct way to construct a `DateTime` object is by parsing the string with

```
DateTime.Parse(string input)
```