# TimeStamp , {"Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Byte[]."}

Tags: c#

getting the error

```
{"Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Byte[]."}
```

i have tried time-stamp but getting the error

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATETIME", SqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364319/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-datetime-to-a-byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql server's timestamp is not a date/time, so you can't convert it to a datetime and vice versa.

See a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Use datetime instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign DateTime to parameter's value, change its type to SqlDbType.DateTime.